# have a TextView with a layout determined a ListAdapter

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a screen where I just simply display the list of items. I have used    `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ClassListActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getItems));`
Now we dont have to create a separate xml layout for this right. But now I want to have a TextView that is the heading of this list may be saying "myItems"..When I try to link a xml layout with this activity, my application stops. and when I try to create a dynamic `TextView`,
this way `TextView tv = new TextView(this);`
and set text in it later. I dont get any errors but I get no results too just the old list no heading..

what should I do? thanks

Comment: could you add some error log and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own XML layout for the ListAdapter. Put the TextView as the heading at the top followed by a ListView widget with the id `@android:id/list`.

See more details here: [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

This one should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp">

 <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#FF0000"
           android:text="My list"/>

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd gotten errors when i tried this before but now I dont. Thanks, but there's still no heading!

Comment: the heading is there but I'm afraid it's covered by the listview. try remove the layout_weight attribute of the listview

Comment: No..I removed layout_weight, I still dont see it.
But can you explain this..when I write two TextViews...The text of the second TextView is displayed as the heading!

Comment: Try remove this: `android:id="@android:id/empty"`from the TextView.